# Spotfire: How to calculate a new column based off a column with blanks using another column to help get the correct value to insert

Tags: spotfire

Example:

```
Name|Number|CALC
----|------|----
a   |123   |a
    |123   |a
a   |123   |a
a   |123   |a
b   |321   |b
    |321   |b
    |321   |b
```

I need to get a calculated column that will find the non-null value in the Name column corresponding to the correct number in the number column so that I can filter by name and get all the data.

Comment: Kevin did the answer work out for you or was your problem more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `Max()` and `Over` statement.

```
Max([Name]) over ([Number])
```

Comment: Awesome @KevinJones  glad to hear it